# C++ Error about "Expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token"

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, svm

I'm trying to load a xml file using a SVM object.

While running this following code:

```
svmNew = SVM::load<SVM>("Liveness_classifier.xml");
```

It's showing the following error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
```

If I change the code like this:

```
svmNew = SVM::load("Liveness_classifier.xml");
```

Then it's showing the following error:

```
(.text+0xa7f): undefined reference to `lbp::OLBP(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone have any solution for this kind of error?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.4 and OpenCV3.4, and this is C++ code.

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation on how to use SVM? What did it say?

Comment: Possible duplicate for the first error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: For your first error, you probably need `SVM::SVM` in between `<` and `>`.    Your second error looks like a linker error which means you probably need `-l` and/or `-L` flags when you compile.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit
Yes I've followed the documentation of SVM but still it didn't work.

Comment: @NathanOliver
Yes the error is duplicate but here the scenario is different and that's not working.

Comment: @Turix
I have changed the code like this:
svmNew = SVM::load<SVM::SVM>("Liveness_classifier.xml");
But still it's not working.
I think this one maybe ok:
svmNew = SVM::load("Liveness_classifier.xml");
But can you give me one example of using -l and/or -L flags when compiling.

Comment: They're two completely different lines of code. Which one did the documentation say to use?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit
The documentation says:
svmNew = SVM::load<SVM>("Liveness_classifier.xml");
this one

Comment: @Turix
I'm using this line to compile:

g++ -std=c++11 demo.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -o demo

If I want to use the -L flags then how can I use this?
Can you please give me an example?